# Identifying polygons overlapping several administrative levels

Tags: qgis, administrative-boundaries

I have information about grid population in a country assigned to polygons; the borders of these polygons are defined by night light intensity. In this way I am able to identify the "real" extent of different urban agglomerations that incidentally go beyond the official administrative borders.

As an example, consider the screenshot attached:
[image]

The yellow polygon represent an urban cluster, the black lines are the administrative border of ADMIN 3; the red lines are the borders of ADMIN 2 (where ADMIN 2>ADMIN 3 in the governance hierarchy). Borders from ADMIN 3 and ADMIN 2 come from two different shape files.

Now, I would like to identify with which ADMIN 2 and/or ADMIN 3 this polygon (and similar others in the country) overlaps. In other words, I would like to create an attribute table that tells me:

polygon with FID 1 is common to/overlaps with ADMIN 2 "xy" and ADMIN 3 "zw".

Is it possible to obtain something similar in QGIS 2.14.3 for Mac?

Comment: The **Join Attributes by Location** tool from the Processing Toolbox could help.

Comment: The only problem I see with that is that it does not allow listing multiple admin areas, since the polys seem to overlap multiple areas.

Comment: You need to run it twice. The first one, using the urban polygon and the ADMIN2 as inputs; the second one, using the previous result and the ADMIN3 as inputs.

Comment: That's not what I was referring to, consider that the yellow polygon overlaps multiple ADMIN2 boundaries, and will therefore need summary statistics (lose the id of the ADMIN area) or the first ADMIN2 poly instead, neither of which is ideal.

Ideal (If I'm interpreting right): ADMIN2overlap = [x,y,z]
Reality: ADMIN2sum/mean/median/etc

Comment: @coneypylon you are right about the overlaps. However, the issue described by the OP could be easily solved with few lines of python code.